# Pantheon on ubuntu 15.10 - mising icon in wingpanel

Tags: 15.10, pantheon, wingpanel

After installing Pantheon on ubuntu 15.10, there is a missing icon in Wingpanel. Only the volume and network icons are visible.

[image: screenshot]
How should I proceed in attempting to fix this missing icon?

Comment: What are "Patheon" and "Wingpanel"? Where do you expect the missing icon to be? What did it look like before it went missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.  I had the same problem and this worked for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/testing

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get install elementary-theme elementary-icon-theme elementary-default-settings elementary-desktop
```

Comment: Can you please describe shortly what these are supposed to do? Just dumping a series of terminal commands does not make a good answer. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)